# Add a vertical scroll to a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble adding a vertical scroll bar. The overflow-y: scroll; doesn't seem to do anything, tried height but that didn't seem to do much either... the container just keeps going off the screen so bottom items cannot be selected

Thank you :)

In my Index.cshtml

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="tree"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin: auto; width: 95%;">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <button id="treeCheckAll" class="gj-button-md">Check All</button>
                <button id="treeUncheckAll" class="gj-button-md">Uncheck All</button>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<button id="selectVolumes" class="btn btn-outline-dark" onclick="selectVolumes()">Select Volumes</button>




function selectVolumes() {
    $("#Container").show(); 
    $("#Container").dialog(); 

    if (tree == null) { 
        tree = $('#tree').tree({ //Gijgo tree
        primaryKey: 'id',
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        dataSource: Menu,
        selectionType: 'multiple',
        checkboxes: true
    });
    $('#treeCheckAll').on('click', function () {
        tree.checkAll();
    });
    $('#treeUncheckAll').on('click', function () {
        tree.uncheckAll();
    });
}
```

}

In bootstrap-grid.css

```
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;        
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to write `overflow-y: scroll` as `overflow-y: scroll !important`

Comment: Thanks @Rana no luck i'm afraid. I can scroll to the bottom of the main window (takes the list south of Antarctica) so can see all of list that way. No scroll bar in Select Volumes list though.

Comment: What are you trying to scroll? What is the overflow-y value of the container holding the sidebar?

Comment: @Shiju Nambiar trying to get the white Select Volumes container to scroll as too many items and goes pass end of map, which is a container-fluid. Overflow-y value is the above failed attempts. Thanks.

Comment: @tj26 try height:auto for the container-fluid or if position attribute of the white select volume is absolute, add a position relative to container-fluid and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the container a max-height:

```
.container-fluid {
  max-height:100vh
}
```